# Limite de votos atingido antes da hora?

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, votos

Segundo o [meu perfil no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto?tab=summary), eu votei 34 vezes hoje. Na aba "votos" do perfil, contei 35. Manualmente, post a post, contei 35 também (sendo 30 em respostas, 4 em perguntas e 1 para fechar).

Sempre achei que o limite diário era de 40 votos (tem até a medalha vox populi para isso), mas o site não está mais me deixando votar.

É bug ou tem algo que não percebi?

Comment: Será que não há diferença de critério do que é um dia em um local e no outro? Você teve paciência (pra não dizer saco :) ) de contar seus votos hoje? E quem sabe tentar ver os que podem ser esses 6 de diferença.

Comment: Na listagem da aba "votos" do perfil, contei 35.

Comment: Terceira fonte então :)

Comment: Ok, contei um a um e deu 35 também (incluindo 1 para fechar). Atualizei a pergunta com todas as contagens. A discrepância 34/35 pode ser cache, mas de 35 para 40 parece bug. Se eu tivesse mesmo estourado o limite, deveria ter ganho a medalha vox populi (se bem que ela ainda pode vir mais tarde).

Comment: Vem mais tarde mesmo. Você tentou ver seus votos antes desses 34? Esses 6 anteriores tem algum horário que pode haver dupla interpretação em que dia foi aplicado? Se não me engano o sistema está em GMT-0400.

Comment: O primeiro voto que considerei de ontem consta como `2013-12-18 11:34:57Z`. São 12+ horas de diferença para hoje (horário de Brasília, né?), então acho que não tem dupla interpretação, @bigown.

Comment: Duvido que esteja relacionado: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146668/different-value-of-votes-in-profile-page-summary-tab-vs-votes-tab

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O [esquema de votos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/184576) <sup>(inglês)</sup>, salvo alguma alteração que eu ainda não conheça, funciona da seguinte forma:

- Todos têm um total de 30 votos.
- Cada um pode ter até 10 votos extras em perguntas.

Temos 40 votos, 30 para qualquer coisa tipo, mas os 10 votos extras estão reservados apenas para perguntas.

#### Estarias com dificuldades em votar por teres votado em muitas respostas?

Sim, o "sistema" está constantemente a calcular (votos em perguntas / total votos) que determina o número de fotos extra que um utilizador vai ter nesse dia.

Ou seja, como votaste em muitas repostas e poucas perguntas, não tiveste direito aos 10 votos extras, tiveste apenas direito a 5 votos extra.

<sup>Isto pode ser lido nos comentários do [esquema de votos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/184576).</sup>

---

Fiz um teste prático onde fui deixar a minha opinião em:

[Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic)

Como votei em muitas das respostas, aos 34 votos o meu limite foi atingido.

Comment: Entendi, foi isso mesmo que aconteceu. E estourei o limite na mesma pergunta que você usou como teste.

Comment: Não conhecia essa regra, achava que era 40 votos indiscriminados. Valeu por explicar (apesar de não entender muito bem como é calculada a quantidade permitida de votos extras em perguntas).