# Reputação sendo mostrada errada no ranking

Tags: bug, suporte, status-intencional

Claro que eu posso não ter entendido a forma como isso é feito ou ter alguma coisa que eu esqueci de observar.

Alguns usuários tem a sua reputação do mês e total idêntica (claro que há a diferença de 1 ponto do início) e outros não. Veja reputação do *bfavaretto* e a minha (*bigown*) em ambos rankings e veja também do *Guilherme*, *zuul*, *Luiz Carvalho*, *Ecil*, *Rodrigo Sassaki*, *Luiz Vieira*. Há uma diferença de 100 pontos, obviamente o bônus de associação, que para estes últimos está entrando como se tivesse ocorrido em outro mês. Quase todos ocorreram no mesmo dia, mas alguns dos últimos citados ocorreram depois, ou seja, se tivesse que considerar que eles estavam em um mês diferente por algum critério maluco, eles deveria estar no mês atual e os dois primeiros usuários citados deveriam estar no mês anterior e ter eles com menos 100 pontos neste mês. Claro que isso é só uma conjectura, estaria errado também, não mudou o mês no dia 11 às 18:00 (ou algo próximo disso). Tem outros exemplos.

- [Reputação por mês](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)
- [Reputação total](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month)

Não é um grande problema, mas parece haver algo errado. Me informem se souberem porque ou se eu [comi bola](http://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/comer_bola).

Isto pode estar relacionada ao problema já apresentado aqui: [Limite de votos atingido antes da hora?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/248/limite-de-votos-atingido-antes-da-hora)

Comment: Eu já havia reparado numa defasagem em alguns usuários. Pensei que era devido ao ranking usar algum *cache*, que seria atualizado em determinados intervalos.

Comment: Cache não é não. Eu esperei para ver se isso era temporário.

Comment: A mesma pergunta, no metão, ainda sem resposta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212471/how-come-my-association-bonus-didnt-count-towards-the-league-but-someone-else

Comment: One shows the reputation *gained*, the other the *total* reputation. The initial `1` rep is never gained -- reputation is always at least 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei de olhar aqui.

Perfil:

- **@bigown**: 961
- **@bfavaretto**: 1,195
- **@mgibsonbr**: 1,547
- **@rodrigorgs**: 1,569

Ranking mês:

- **@bigown**: 960
- **@bfavaretto**: 1,194
- **@mgibsonbr**: 1,546
- **@rodrigorgs**: **1,458**

Ranking total:

- **@bigown**: 961
- **@bfavaretto**: 1,195
- **@mgibsonbr**: 1,547
- **@rodrigorgs**: 1,569

Os dados são do site principal, não do meta.

Enfim, para mim apenas o **@rodrigorgs** está errado no ranking do mês.

Comment: Muito estranho, pra mim o mgibsonbr agora está correto, mas não estava, mas tem outros que estão errados, vou citar lá.